# Website scrolling stops for a tiny time when reaching a specific spot

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

If i refresh the page and scroll down, the website lags for a few milliseconds and continues afterwards. the problem is only coming back after I refresh the page.
Any possible solutions for that?
Thanks

Comment: This might be due to heavy processing or GPU loads at that point of the webpage. It would be easy to investigate if you come up with the website...

Comment: I found the problem, it was lagging because of the parallax effect

Answer (score 0):

try to add this.see if it helps. clear your cache and try to run in in a different browser if thats a browser problem.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. I[image: scrol behabiour] write a simple code for scroll behavior watch my codepen link and

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#test1 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

#test2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>

<div class="main" id="test1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</p>
  <a href="#test2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
  <p>Note: Remove the scroll-behavior property to remove smooth scrolling.</p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="test2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <a href="#test1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The scroll-behavior property is not supported in Internet Explorer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest this:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```